# With redux-saga, how can I takeLeading based on action params as well as type?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So say I dispatch 4 actions to make async calls via redux-saga like so:

```
{type: REQUEST_API_THING, title: 'Foo'}
{type: REQUEST_API_THING, title: 'Bar'}
{type: REQUEST_API_THING, title: 'Foo'}
{type: REQUEST_API_THING, title: 'Foo'}
```

....none of which will complete before the last action has been dispatched. If I attach my saga like:

```
yield takeLeading(REQUEST_API_THING, fetchApiThing);
```

only the first request will be completed. The others will be ignored. I want all requests with that unique `title` param to be completed though, so in this example, only the last 2 should be ignored. How do I do that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you have explicit list of titles then you can make more specific watchers by passing a function instead of an action type to the take* effect creator as first param.

```
yield takeLeading(({type, title}) => type === 'REQUEST_API_THING' && title === 'Foo', fetchApiThing);
yield takeLeading(({type, title}) => type === 'REQUEST_API_THING' && title === 'Bar', fetchApiThing);
```

This won't work when you don't know the titles beforehand. Redux-saga as far as I know doesn't have a built-in way to deal with that, however you can write your own utility method like this:

```
function takeLeadingWithParam(typeOrPattern, param, saga, ...args) {
    const instanceMap = new Map();
    return fork(function * () {
        yield takeEvery(typeOrPattern, function* (action) {
            const key = typeof param === 'function' ? param(action) : action[param];
            if (!instanceMap.get(key)) {
                const task = yield fork(saga, action, ...args);
                instanceMap.set(key, task);
                yield join(task);
                instanceMap.delete(key);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
yield takeLeadingWithParam('REQUEST_API_THING', 'title', fetchApiThing);
```

Or like this for some more complicated logic:

```
yield takeLeadingWithParam('REQUEST_API_THING', ({id, title}) => id + ':' + title, fetchApiThing);
```

Note that I just written this utility method down so I may have missed something in the implementation.